# Format an SD card from TWRP recovery using shell

Tags: sd-card, twrp, shell, partitions, formatting

I'm trying to format/partition an SD card (that was used as an encrypted storage on an android phone) because it only shows as 15 MB while it's supposed to be 2 GB.

I was intending to install a ROM from TWRP recovery but made a mistake and wiped everything including the SD card and selected "format" to remove encryption but forgot that the SD card had the zip to be installed...

I don't have access to a reliable USB cable which is probably why adb sideloading didn't work for me.

Here is what I tried from the TWRP terminal:

```
~ # df -h
Filesystem              Size      Used    Available   Used   Mounted on
tmpfs                   361.1M    16.0K   361.1M      0%     /dev
tmpfs                   361.1M    20.0K   361.1M      0%     /tmp
/dev/block/mmcblk0p19   2.2G      38.7M   2.1G        2%     /data
/dev/block/mmcblk0p19   2.2G      38.7M   2.1G        2%     /sdcard
/dev/block/mmcblk0p16   196.8M    4.4M    192.4M      2%     /cache
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1    16.0M     24.0K   15.9M       0%     /external_sd
```

(Why `tmpfs` and `mkcblk0p19` listed twice with different mount points?)

I know that the block `mmcblk1` is the sd card because it disappears when I physically remove it and reboot.

I tried the following:

```
~ # umount -f /dev/block/mmcblk1p1
...

~ # fdisk /dev/block/mmcblk1
Found valid GPT with protective MBR: using GPT

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/block/mmcblk1: 3862528 sectors, 1886M
Logical sector size: 512
Disk identifier (GUID): ...
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3862494
Number   Start (sector) End (sector) Size Code Name
1    2048   34815   16.0M   0700   android_meta
2    34816   3862494    1868M   0700 android_expand

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1

Command (m for help): d
No partition is defined yet!

Command (m for help): n
Command action
    e    extended
    p primary partition (1-4)
p
Partition number (1-4): 1
First cylinder (1-239, default 1):
Last cylinder or +size or +sizeM or +sizeK (1-239, default 239):
...
Command (m for help): w
...
```

But it didn't change anything.

And, I see the files `/dev/block/mmcblk1`, `/dev/block/mmcblk1p1` and `/dev/block/mmcblk1p2`.

But `mmcblk1p2` is not in fstab:

```
 ~ # cat /etc/fstab
 /dev/block/mmcblk0p17  /system       ext4  rw  0  0
 /dev/block/mmcblk0p19  /data         ext4  rw  0  0
 /dev/block/mmcblk0p16  /cache        ext4  rw  0  0
 /dev/block/mmcblk0p15  /efs          ext4  rw  0  0
 /dev/block/mmcblk1p1   /external_sd  vfat  rw  0  0
```

I don't have a card reader but I tried the sd card in another phone and plugged it to windows and it shows 16 MB there as well.

**Question: How do I format the sd card from android terminal so that I can use it normally again?**

Comment: I managed to boot into the OS and therefore I fixed my issue since android prompt to format the sd card as external or internal storage. But it would be really nice for someone to help others who might be dealing with the same issue and need to do this from shell in recovery mode.

Comment: `tmpfs` is a virtual filesystem which lives in RAM. It's usually mounted a score of places. `mkcblk0p19` is mounted at `/data` and bind-mounted to SD card. // You can insert the card when running in ROM and Android will prompt you to format as portable storage. // Otherwise you need to create partition of DOS type, not Linux. // `fdisk` is not the right tool to manipulate GPT, better create DOS partition table. // Changes to partitions may require `partprobe`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you. `partprobe` is not available, and with no internet I suppose it can't be just downloaded. So are there any alternatives or is this simply not possibly from the recovery shell? Also, I'm still searching and trying to understand your comment, especially the part about creating a DOS partition table...